# Comparing Time extracted from a Datetime column with a Static time in MariaDB and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mariadb

I have a database with a bunch of messages sent between a set of people and each message has a timestamp in a date-time format. I'm extracting the time from this date-time column and attempting to compare it with a static timestamp to see how many messages were sent after that time by each user. The code I'm using for that is as follows:

```
SELECT sender_id, SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%H:%i:%s')>CAST('17:00:00' AS time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no_msgs_afterhours GROUP BY sender_id;
```

The funny thing is this works perfectly in the MariaDB database instance but in the MySQL instance it gives me this error:

> ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations
>   (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for
>   operation '>'

The MariaDB instance is version 5.5.32 and the MySQL instance is 5.5.29. Could this be a MySQL  version issue? I read online that there used to be similar collation issues with MySQL 4.1.8 and earlier but that shouldn't apply here.

Comment: Have the server instances got different default collations? What's the output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%colla%';` on each server?

Comment: Both server instances have the same default collations: collation_connection = utf8_general_ci, collation_database = utf8_general_ci, collation_server = latin1_swedish_ci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have different default collations for server and database / connection. The `DATE_FORMAT()` function produces a latin1_swedish_ci collation and compares it with the database collation.

Write it like this and it will work:

```
SELECT sender_id, SUM(CASE WHEN TIME(created_at) > CAST('17:00:00' AS time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no_msgs_afterhours GROUP BY sender_id;
```

Note: You're missing a FROM clause ;)

You don't even need to cast as time:

```
SELECT sender_id, SUM(CASE WHEN TIME(created_at) > '17:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no_msgs_afterhours GROUP BY sender_id;
```

You can see how it works with this little test script:

```
create table foo (dt datetime, ts timestamp);
insert into foo values (NOW(), NOW());

/*doesn't work*/
SELECT 
CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ts,'%H:%i:%s')>CAST('17:00:00' AS time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
FROM foo;

/*works*/
SELECT 
CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(ts,'%H:%i:%s')>'17:00:00'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
FROM foo;

/*works*/
SELECT 
CASE WHEN TIME(ts)>'17:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
FROM foo;

/*works*/
SELECT 
CASE WHEN TIME(ts)>CAST('17:00:00' AS time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
FROM foo;
```